# Updating Checkbox Field Based on Formula Field

Tags: salesforcedx, formula-field, checkbox

- I have 2 Custom and 1 Standard Object: Subscription_c, Term_c, Account
- Subscription_c has a lookup relationship with Term_c, called Subterm__c
- Subscription_c has also a lookup relationship with Account, called Subaccount__c
- Terms_c and Subscription__c have formula(text) field status, and Term__c's status automatically updates Subscription_c's status.
- All updates happen on Term_c objects' Start Date and End Date.
- Account has a checkbox called SubscriptionActive.
- I need to update SubscriptionActive checkbox based on -Subscriptions__c's Status (when (Active, checkbox checked), when (Inactive, checkbox unchecked).
- I have tried a lot of ways to solve this problem but have had no success.
- I built a process builder to solve this problem, but without editing any field on Subscription__c object, it doesn't update the check box.
- IF([Subscription_c.Status__c = "Active", True, False)
- I know that Formula Field is not an ideal field to use for Status and has problems updating other fields.

May I know if there is any other way to solve it.

Comment: I am guessing the `Status` field on Subscription get changes/calculated when `Start Date` and `End date` on term changes. This is the event where your flow should be written, not on status change which is a formula and will not trigger any automation. How does the status on `Term` gets changed?

Comment: There is a formula for the Term's Status Field, which is related to the end and start date fields of the Term. Subscription's Status has the formula Subscriptions_c.Subterm_r.Status__c, which is just being updated by Term's Status field.

Comment: @crmprogdev Do you have any suggestions on this Trigger?